Short sci-fi story about gold-skinned alien mercenaries that different nations frantically bid on
The story is about aliens who arrive on earth. Their species have gold skin I think and they are mercenaries out of work looking to be hired on for the country that can pay the most. This leads to a frantic bidding war that devolves to a coalition of western countries led by the US and a coalition of the east led by the Soviet Union. The story was written in the 1970's or 1980's. The west wins the bidding and the Soviets launch a nuclear first strike. The aliens will eventually become a wealthy ruling class.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember if you read this in a magazine or an anthology?

I believe it was a anthology.
